# Show/hide div at offset / anchor point / variable px height from top of the page - let jQuery read out the 'offset/anchor' position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I have a showing/hiding menubar after scrolling 473px from the top.
Now I figured out, that on other pages I need to show/hide it at different px offset (because of a bigger picture at the top for example).

So theoretically as I scroll over the 'anchor', jQuery checks "yup there is the 'anchor' - now show .themenu".

```
// Menu bar after scrolling X px
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $(window).scroll(function(){                          
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 473) {
            $('.themenu').fadeIn(10);

        } else {
            $('.themenu').fadeOut(10);
        }
     }); // EOF scroll
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this by using `.offset().top` for the element you need the scroll to make action when reach it

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        var elementoffset = $('#elementhere').offset(); // <<< change #elementhere with your element you want the scroll to make action when reach it                         
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > elementoffset.top) {
            $('.themenu').fadeIn(10);

        } else {
            $('.themenu').fadeOut(10);
        }
     }); // EOF scroll
```

Comment: works flawless, thanks! So easy I probably should have found this while searching. Have a good one!

Comment: @ezkay you're totally welcome .. and while we spend more times coding sometimes we missed things while it already front of us .. This is always happening to all of us .. Very Good Luck to you :)